# How do I avoid conflicts from extremely deferred JS files?

Tags: javascript

I have a plugin that is currently installed on about 30,000 WordPress websites. In some cases, we find customers doing everything in their power to increase their page load speeds. This is certainly a good goal to have as we all know it can affect SEO, user experience and whatnot.

A common problem, however, is that when people move things around or defer them to much, it can create conflicts. In fact, in some cases, I'm actually seeing the DOM loaded event firing off prior to the scripts being loaded. I have a tiny snippet of code that is output via PHP because it is dynamic and contains variables from the server that will be passed to the functions in the JS file.

However, if the DOM loaded event fires off meaning that the files should already be loaded, but they aren't, then I get calls to undefined functions errors. I'm sure you've all seen those before.

So I'm contemplating using a setInterval to check for the existence of my JS files functions before moving forward and then immediately clearing the interval as soon as the function becomes available.

In 90% of cases, the setInterval will never fire off more than just the one time. In the small percentage of cases where they have something unusual going on, it will defer the running of the functions until the code is available.

Here's a make believe example that exemplifies exactly what I'm referring to:

```
var check_for_my_function = setInterval( function() {
    if('function' === typeof my_function ) {
        my_function();
        clearInterval(check_for_my_function);
    }
} , 250 );
```

Is this a safe and efficient way to do this or is there an actual function that is better suited for accomplishing this kind of delay? I always assumed that I would be safe listening for the DOM loaded event, but even that tends to be premature in some extreme use cases.

Comment: A decent, if somewhat dated, article about the many things authors do that screws up script loading: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/. Just sayin', you're not alone.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcCaughan. That was a confusing and depressing roller coaster of a read. Buy yeah, it sure characterizes how I feel right now. :-)